# Not able to add entities to a azure storage table in node.js when deployed to cloud?

Tags: node.js, azure, guid, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am using socket.io in node.js to implement chat functionality in my azure cloud project. In it i have been adding the user chat history to tables using node.js. It works fine when i run it on my local emulator, but strangely when i deploy to my azure cloud it doesnt work and it doesnt throw up any error either so its really mind boggling. Below is my code.

```
 var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , sio = require('socket.io')
 , redis = require('redis');

var client = redis.createClient();
var io = sio.listen(server,{origins: '*:*'});

io.set("store", new sio.RedisStore);

process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT = "account";
process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY = "key";

var azure = require('azure');
var chatTableService = azure.createTableService();

createTable("ChatUser");

server.listen(4002);

 socket.on('privateChat', function (data) {        
    var receiver = data.Receiver;
    console.log(data.Username);

    var chatGUID1 = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });

 var chatRecord1 = {
        PartitionKey: data.Receiver,
        RowKey: data.Username,
        ChatID: chatGUID2,
        Username: data.Receiver,
        ChattedWithUsername: data.Username,
        Timestamp: new Date(new Date().getTime())
    };
    console.log(chatRecord1.Timestamp);

    queryEntity(chatRecord1);
}

function queryEntity(record1) {
chatTableService.queryEntity('ChatUser'
, record1.PartitionKey
, record1.RowKey
, function (error, entity) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log("Entity already exists")
    }
    else {
        insertEntity(record1);            
    }
})    
}

function insertEntity(record) {
chatTableService.insertEntity('ChatUser', record, function (error) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log("Entity inserted");
    }        
});
}
```

Its working on my local emulator but not on cloud and I came across a reading that DateTime variable of an entity should not be null when creating a record on cloud table. But am pretty sure the way am passing timestamp is fine, it is right? any other ideas why it might be working on local but not on cloud?

EDIT:

I hav also been getting this error when am running the socket.io server, but in spite of this error the socket.io functionality is working fine so i didnt bother to care about it. I have no idea what the error means in the first place.

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple things:

- You shouldn't need to set Timestamp, the service should be populating that automatically when you insert a record.
- When running it locally you can set the environment variables to the Windows Azure storage account settings and see if it will successfully write to the table when running on your developer box. Instead of running in the emulator, just set the environment variables and run the app directly with node.exe.

Are you running in a web role or worker role? I'm assuming it's a cloud service since you mentioned the emulator. If it's a worker role, maybe add some instrumentation to log to file to assist in debugging. If it's a web role you can add an iisnode.yml file in the root of the application, with the following line in the file to enable logging of stdout/stderr:

```
loggingEnabled: true
```

This will capture stdout/stderr to an iislog folder under the approot folder on e: or f: of the web role instance. You can remote desktop to the instance and look at the logs to see if the logs you have for successful insertion are occurring.

Otherwise, it's not obvious from the code above what's going on. Similar code worked fine for me. Relevant bits for my test code can be found at https://gist.github.com/Blackmist/5326756.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Firstly, Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! Ya i did try setting the environment variables to azure storage on my local and it works. And it also works when i run the node.js script directly from node.exe by doing RDP on the web role. But it doesnt work when iisnode handles the node.js script. Strange!

Comment: I put a iisnode.yml in both the E: directory and approot, but there were no logs in the approot folder. Where should i put it?

Comment: Btw what is the best way to start a socket.io server? through a command prompt or through iisnode?

Comment: The iisnode.yml file should be directly in approot. I've never tried adding it through remote desktop, but I assume you will need to recycle the instance, or at least recycle IIS, to have it recognized. Normally I just add it to the webrole directory in my project and deploy that way.

The iisnode directory created by it should be directly off approot also, and will contain an index.html file and a test file for stdout/stderr out. Actually one of each per instance of node on the machine.

Comment: For starting a server, you mean when remoting into the service instance? Definitely through IIS/IISNode, as this is how it will run normally. IIS will provide lifecycle management like starting up new node instances, recycling them, etc.

Comment: But when i start with IISNode, the socket.io server gets shut down if its not being used after a certain period of time. I have to start it again and again from the browser. Is this normal behaviour or i can fix this in any way? Thanks a lot for your help again

Comment: I'm going to guess this is IIS recycling the application pool. There are default idle time and other triggers that will cause IIS to recycle the process. This is the most likely thing. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2008/04/22/disable-recycling-in-iis-7-use-appcmd.aspx) has some information on disabling it through the UI, which you can use to test if this is the problem. If it is, then you can probably add a powershell script to disable it when the role starts up.

Comment: and [this discussion](http://serverfault.com/questions/347199/how-can-i-set-iis-application-pool-recycle-times-without-resorting-to-the-ugly-s) talks about using PowerShell to modify IIS application pool settings.